# Can't get to the properties of the datacontext

Tags: binding

I have a Grid in a User Control that's placed in a Window that has 2 collections.

I'm looking for a way to get to Collection 2 from within my grid.

I already tried a couple of things:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Bicycles, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
 AncestorType={x:Type CollectionContainer}}}" />
```

and

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource=
{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window, AncestorLevel=1}, 
Path=DataContext.Bicycles}" DisplayMemberPath="Height" />
```

and

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource=
{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Companies}" 
/>
```

But everytime my combobox ends up empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your app you should look in your 'Output' window that will tell you the binding errors that come up. So it will give you a clue as to what you're doing wrong.

It looks like you don't need the prefix `DataContext.` the datacontext of a child control is the datacontext of it's parent by default unless otherwise specified. So if the DataContext of the Window is some ViewModel the UserControl and it's child controls will have the same datacontext.

So you should probably only have to do this:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Companies}" />
```

Comment: No, the actual error was that I put down x:Type Window, which wasn't the case, since Prism was used and everything was a user control. That and the fact I should've gone up two levels.